# Not able to Expand the div inside a Popper in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to implement a feature via CSS but am not able to do so.
[image: This is the issue]

As you can see, when I click the "See link options" button, the content loads, but it spills out of the popper.
What I'm attempting to accomplish here is that when I click on this button, the content should load and the popper should expand in height so that the content is filled but does not overflow.

`overflow: auto` <== This results in a scroller inside the container (Popper), which I don't want.
I have also used `min-height: 300px` but that is also not working.
I have [uploaded the code on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/adityaxrawal/Notion-Share-Widget/draft/nostalgic-tree?file=%2Fsrc%2FComponents%2FApp%2FApp.js&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522cla52fooa000jl1ig0ymd7qnh%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cla52gkr900a0356jmuqiqi47%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cla52ghic007f356jkc795i89%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a fixed height of 200px on the `.Body` element. Use `min-height` to allow the container to expand to display the options.

```css
.Body{
    min-height: 200px; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @jme11 you have just saved my day. I am really grateful. I was knowing it can be fixed with `min-height` but I was just not able to find it where I am missing. Thank you so much.